# How to find the distinct record from mongodb using grails

Tags: mongodb, grails

I am very much new to grails. I am running in a situation where i need to find the distinct records from a mongodb collection. I tried some examples but was not successfull

The following code gives me all the records from a collection. however I need only distinct records using "userName" as a distinct criteria

```
def eventMyOrders = EventMyOrders.findAllByEventId( eventID,[sort: 'endEventDateTime', order: 'desc'])
```

Gives me all the orders from a "EventMyOrders" collection.

How can i use distinct ( Or Group By ) to find the records with distinct "userName" with the query. Any help shall be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use criteria query if you want just a list of distinct usernames:

```
def criteria = EventMyOrders.createCriteria()
def eventsWithDistinctUserName = criteria.list {
    projections {
        distinct("username")
    }
}
```

where `"username"` is the name of the property for username in EventMyOrders.

If you want a list of EventMyOrders with distinct usernames you can use either HQL query:

```
  EventMyOrders.executeQuery("select distinct username from EventMyOrders")
```

or just filter out not-unique records from results the Groovy way:

```
  EventMyOrders.list().unique {a,b -> a.username <=> b.username}
```

Comment: This will give me array of usernames but not entire record. I already tried this